# how to solve this error of Search?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **I have a problem with my Search here is my code :**

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(string Seach_Data, string findby, int? page, string currentFilter )
{
    if (findby == "fname")
    {
        string query = "SELECT v.h_no as h_no, v.h_initials , v.h_id as h_id , t.titles as titles, p.Suburb as Suburb, p.flatNo as flatNo, p.flatName as flatName,v.Email as Email, v.cell as cell,  v.tel_h as tel_h,  v.fname as fname, p.strname as strname, p.strNo as strNo, p.City as City, LEFT(v.lname, 255) as lname from [dbo].[Heads] v, [dbo].[Addresses1] p, [dbo].[Titles] t WHERE v.[h_ID] = p.[h_id] and v.[title_id]= t.[title_id] ";

        var ViewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<HeadsViewModel>(query);
        return View(ViewModel.Where(x => x.fname == Seach_Data).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6));
    }
    else if (findby == "lname")
    {
        string query = "SELECT v.h_no as h_no, v.h_initials , v.h_id as h_id , t.titles as titles, p.Suburb as Suburb, p.flatNo as flatNo, p.flatName as flatName,v.Email as Email, v.cell as cell,  v.tel_h as tel_h,  v.fname as fname, p.strname as strname, p.strNo as strNo, p.City as City, LEFT(v.lname, 255) as lname from [dbo].[Heads] v, [dbo].[Addresses1] p, [dbo].[Titles] t WHERE v.[h_ID] = p.[h_id] and v.[title_id]= t.[title_id] ";
        var ViewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<HeadsViewModel>(query);

        return View(ViewModel.Where(x => x.lname == Seach_Data).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6));  
    }
    else if (findby == "h_no")
    {
        string query = "SELECT v.h_no as h_no, v.h_initials , v.h_id as h_id , t.titles as titles, p.Suburb as Suburb, p.flatNo as flatNo, p.flatName as flatName,v.Email as Email, v.cell as cell,  v.tel_h as tel_h,  v.fname as fname, p.strname as strname, p.strNo as strNo, p.City as City, LEFT(v.lname, 255) as lname from [dbo].[Heads] v, [dbo].[Addresses1] p, [dbo].[Titles] t WHERE v.[h_ID] = p.[h_id] and v.[title_id]= t.[title_id] ";
        var ViewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<HeadsViewModel>(query);
        return View(ViewModel.Where(x => x.h_no == Seach_Data).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6));
    }
    else
    {
        string query = "SELECT v.h_no as h_no, v.h_initials , v.h_id as h_id , t.titles as titles, p.Suburb as Suburb, p.flatNo as flatNo, p.flatName as flatName,v.Email as Email, v.cell as cell,  v.tel_h as tel_h,  v.fname as fname, p.strname as strname, p.strNo as strNo, p.City as City, LEFT(v.lname, 255) as lname from [dbo].[Heads] v, [dbo].[Addresses1] p, [dbo].[Titles] t WHERE v.[h_ID] = p.[h_id] and v.[title_id]= t.[title_id] ";
        var ViewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<HeadsViewModel>(query);
        return View(ViewModel.ToList().ToPagedList( page ?? 1,6));
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Heads", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        <b> Find by name:</b>@Html.RadioButton("findBy", "fname") <text>First Name</text>
        @Html.RadioButton("findBy", "lname")<text>Last Name</text><br />
        @Html.RadioButton("findBy", "h_no")<text>Header Number</text><br />
        @Html.TextBox("Seach_Data", ViewBag.FilterValue as string, ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Find" />
    </p>
}
```

```
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, findby = Request.QueryString["findby"], Seach_Data = Request.QueryString["Seach_Data"] }))
```

my problem is, when i search using Fname or lname it does not display but when i search using H_no it is displaying, please help.

Answer (score 0):

On running the bare bones of your code I can see that it is getting the correct values for findby what I did not use in test app is this portion;

```
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, findby = Request.QueryString["findby"], Seach_Data = Request.QueryString["Seach_Data"] }))
```

below is a screen grab where it successfully hits and gets the correct findby value. Can you check your query if that is the problem?
[image]

Comment: why would you say that!

Comment: Let me say didn't get your answer

Comment: There is none it's all working with your code only :)

Comment: can you please check my screenshot that i just added now.